# In Java Mail, how to use SMTP Service extension to overcome the 1000 line length limit?

Tags: java, email, smtp

My mail sending code is like this:

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport( "smtp" );
transport.connect( mailServer, userName, password);
transport.send( message ); // message is a MimeMessage
```

And my mail contains some text attachments which have very long lines. I found that one of the attachment's long line was broken into two lines automatically.

RFC5312 indicate that

> The maximum total length of a text line including the  is 1000 octets (not counting the leading dot duplicated for transparency). This number may be increased by the use of SMTP Service Extensions.

But how could I use SMTP Service Extensions in Java Mail? How could I overcome this line length limit in SMTP.

Comment: And why don't you just conform to this limit by using the appropriate methods?

Comment: cannot conform to this limit, since that will break client's automatic process

Comment: Which means the client is broken. MIME message generation/decoding has been there for ages and works. If this is all it takes, just enforce base64 encoding of all text parts...

Comment: don't know how to do that, could you show a example?